# SMS reader with import to database with Xamarin and C#

Tags: c#, android, database, xamarin, sms

I am developing an Android app that will read any received SMSs and post them in an online database. I want all of this to happen in the background so no UI involved. Just a receiver and a intent service.

So what I tried is to create a broadcast receiver that will look for received SMSs and as soon as it finds one it will start a service that will post the SMS in the database. I managed to get this to work with an UI opened with another code. But I want this to be possible without having to open my app.

Here is my code for now. Is something wrong? One thing to mention is that if I open the app and receive a message then the app crashes! If anyone can help me I'd appreciate it a lot!

**SmsReciever** (I know I wrote receiver wrong)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Telephony;
using Android.Provider;

namespace Services_Log
{
    [BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Label = "SMS Receiver")]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" })]
    public class SmsReciever : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        private const string Tag = "SMSBroadcastReceiver";
        private const string IntentAction = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            try
            {
                Intent smsIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(SmsService));
                if (intent.Action != IntentAction) return;
                SmsMessage[] messages = Telephony.Sms.Intents.GetMessagesFromIntent(intent);
                for (int i=0; i<messages.Length; i++)
                {
                    smsIntent.PutExtra("sms_number", messages[i].OriginatingAddress);
                    smsIntent.PutExtra("sms_body", messages[i].MessageBody);
                    context.StartService(smsIntent);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(context, ex.Message, ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**SmsService**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Data;
using Android.Service;

namespace Services_Log
{
    [Service]
    public class SmsService : IntentService
    {
        public SmsService () : base("SmsService")
        {

        }

        protected override void OnHandleIntent(Intent intent)
        {
            Context context = this;
            Toast.MakeText(context,"Service Started", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("Server=db4free.net;Port=3306;database=testdbs;User Id=venoom;Password=takefree1;charset=utf8");

            string smsNumber = intent.GetStringExtra("sms_number");
            string smsBody = intent.GetStringExtra("sms_body");

            try
            {
                con.Open();
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO tableTest(number,message) VALUES(@number,@message)");
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@number",smsNumber);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@message", smsBody);
                Toast.MakeText(context, "Succsesfully uploaded to database!", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(context, ex.Message, ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**(Left blank)

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace Services_Log
{
    [Activity(Label = "Services_Log", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            // SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
        }
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="Services_Log.Services_Log" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS" />
    <application android:label="Services Log" android:icon="@drawable/Icon">
        <receiver android:name="SmsReciever">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    <receiver android:name=".SmsReciever">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are doing something wrong.

**Receiver**

Do **not add the services manually** to your `AndroidManifest.xml`. By using the `BroadcastReceiver`, `IntentFilter` and `Services` attributes, you are telling the xamarin compiler to generate an entry for these receivers, services, activities, ... in the AndroidManifest. You can verify this by openening the generated AndroidManifest.xml in `obj\Debug\android`

```xml
<receiver android:enabled="true" android:label="SMS Receiver" android:name="md563471986402eafe51037cbcf251950c3.SmsReciever">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
   <receiver android:name="mono.android.Seppuku">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="mono.android.intent.action.SEPPUKU" />
    <category android:name="mono.android.intent.category.SEPPUKU.SmsApp.SmsApp" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service android:name="md563471986402eafe51037cbcf251950c3.SmsService" />
```

and run your UI stuff in the UI thread.

```cs
var handler = new Handler(Looper.MainLooper);
handler.Post(() =>
{
    Toast.MakeText(context, $"{smsNumber}: {smsBody}", ToastLength.Long).Show();
});
```

**Database**

Do **never connect to a remote database directly**. You are giving away the database password by publishing your app! The best practice is: always use a webservice in between.